# Как сделать потоковое вещание музыки на сайте

Tags: python, node.js, django, nginx, аудио

Хочу сделать онлайн радио по типу этого https://listen.moe
Так как опыта у меня немного, вопрос как реализовать такое вещание музыки, поставил меня в тупик. Пересмотрел много ответов, но мои познания не позволяют мне разобраться. Сам вопрос в том, какой самый простой способ будет реализовать это?
Бэкэнд у меня на django, но как я понял нужен асинхронный фреймворк, node.js поможет справиться с этим?

Comment: Минус за спам меток. Убрал метку C#, рекомендую не пытаться возвращать обратно, чтобы ещё минусов не огрести от постоянных читателей C#.

Answer (score 1):

Потоковое вещание сейчас очень сложно делается. Но есть альтернатива.

Добавляешь на сайт тег аудио и кнопку плей (без кнопки звук не запустится)

В теге аудио делаешь ссылку на m3u8 плейлист - этот плейлист создаешь динамически.

В плейлист ставишь 2 трека. В первый ссылку на композицию которая играет в данный момент, во второй ссылку на этот же плейлист. Получается рекурсия.

Асинхронный фреймворк тут не нужен если файлы отдаешь напрямую вэб сервером.

Если нужно реальное время - нарезай файлы помельче.

Если делать бэкэнд не сама цель - используй старый добый айскаст

Comment: "Если делать бэкэнд не сама цель - используй старый добый айскаст", немного не понял про это.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743279/how-could-i-play-a-shoutcast-icecast-stream-using-html5 и тд